# How can I pass @VAR + magic numbers to a stored procedure parameter in a sql script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Lets say I have a stored proc call `MyStoredProc` which recieved an int `(@MyParam INT)` datatype.

Let's say I have an int declared in a script like this...

```
DECLARE @MyVar INT ;
SET @MyVar = 101 ;
```

I just wrote a long sql script where I do a LOT of this...

```
EXEC MyStoredProc @MyVar + 1  ;
```

I am shocked that this is causing a syntax error warning.

I can do this...

```
EXEC MyStoredProc @MyVar ;
```

and I can do this...

```
EXEC MyStoredProc 101 ;
```

but I can't do this...

```
EXEC MyStoredProc @MyVar + 1  ;
```

This is going to make my script a LOT harder to write unless I am missing something.  This is for SQL 2005.

Comment: `EXEC MyStoredProc @MyVar + @MyVar2` doesn't work either. [Vote up the item here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/352110/t-sql-use-scalar-functions-as-stored-procedure-parameters)

Comment: Yep...I fixed up the question.

Comment: ...thanks for the link to the upvote...done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option I see is to declare a temp variable:

```
declare @var1_increment = @var1 + 1
exec stored_proc @var1_increment
```

And create a Connect and User Voice topics proposing to extend T-SQL syntax.

Answer (score 2):

If you add @MyVar + @MyVar2 there is a possibility that could overflow an integer, that may be a one reason.

By the way following is not working on sql server 2008

```
EXEC MyStoredProc @MyVar + @MyVar2;
```

I think you can do the addition before calling the stored procedure (as per @adatishchev) or pass two parameters to the stored procedure and add them inside the stored procedure.

```
EXEC MyStoredProc @MyVar, @MyVar2;

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProc]

     @MyVar INT,
     @MyVar2 INT
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT @MyVar += @MyVar2;

END
```

Comment: Kaf, Not sure why I thought I tried it and it workd but you are correct (when I tried it again) you can't send two VARS to the parameter.  I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: ...and yes you can do the additions before which is what I was hoping to avoid.  In my very long list of parameterized inserts I was hoping to avoid de-prettifying my script with SET statements.  Alas that was not to be.  But I WAS able to put the SET statements at the END of each statement and kept it mostly prettified.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: +1 creating a second param in the sproc is a good workaround - surely quite easy to implement without too much pain